# javascript How to display div's always open?

Tags: javascript

[image]

I want to show all the div are always open now it's working onclick function .

```
<form type="post">
 <span class="btn btn-theme-dark" onclick="load_address_form();">
</form> 

function load_address_form(){
        //document.getElementById(delivery_address).style.display = 'block';
        var top = Number(200);
        $('.delivery_address').html('<div style="text-align:center;width:100%;height:'+(top*2)+'px; top:'+top+'px;display:block;"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i></div>');

        $('.delivery_address').load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/cart_checkout/delivery_address',
            function(){
                var top_off = $('.header').height();
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".delivery_address").offset().top-(2*top_off)
                }, 1000);
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function when site has loaded:

```
window.onload = function(){
load_address_form();
}
```

Comment: no its not working i want load this page <?php echo base_url(); ?>home/cart_checkout/delivery_address

Comment: You are welcome! Does it work like you expected? In my answer i suggest to call the function load_address_form(); which is responsible for loading the page <?php echo base_url(); ?>home/cart_checkout/delivery_address